# How to resolve cross-origin frame loading on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cross-domain, sap-commerce-cloud

iframe loading is failing for my site in Chrome, but working fine on Firefox.

PFA for snapshot for the error message:

[image]

Error message in chrome:

> Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:9001" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
>       at Object.FCKTools.FixDocumentParentWindow (http://localhost:9001/cmscockpit/zkau/web/js/ext/FCKeditor/editor/js/fckeditorcode_gecko.js:7:42291)
>       at Object.FCKTools.FixDocumentParentWindow (http://localhost:9001/cmscockpit/zkau/web/js/ext/FCKeditor/editor/js/fckeditorcode_gecko.js:7:42372)
>       at Object.FCKTools.FixDocumentParentWindow (http://localhost:9001/cmscockpit/zkau/web/js/ext/FCKeditor/editor/js/fckeditorcode_gecko.js:7:42372)
>       at Object.FCKTools.GetDocumentWindow (http://localhost:9001/cmscockpit/zkau/web/js/ext/FCKeditor/editor/js/fckeditorcode_gecko.js:7:42168)
>       at Object.FCKTools.GetElementWindow (http://localhost:9001/cmscockpit/zkau/web/js/ext/FCKeditor/editor/js/fckeditorcode_gecko.js:7:42032)
>       at FCKToolbarFontSizeCombo.FCKToolbarSpecialCombo.Create (http://localhost:9001/cmscockpit/zkau/web/js/ext/FCKeditor/editor/js/fckeditorcode_gecko.js:7:204406)
>       at FCKToolbar.Create (http://localhost:9001/cmscockpit/zkau/web/js/ext/FCKeditor/editor/js/fckeditorcode_gecko.js:7:220569)
>       at FCKToolbarSet.Load (http://localhost:9001/cmscockpit/zkau/web/js/ext/FCKeditor/editor/js/fckeditorcode_gecko.js:7:225568)
>       at LoadToolbar (http://localhost:9001/cmscockpit/zkau/web/js/ext/FCKeditor/editor/fckeditor.html?InstanceName=z_1t_ld5!ed:194:15)
>       at Object.StartNext (:1:644)

Warning in firefox:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user’s experience. For more help http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/

Not sure why the cross-origin error is coming up here, because the protocol, domain and the port are same in both the places.

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons:

1) The server is blocking the content to open in an iframe. To be implemented at server.
2) CORS. To be implemented at server.